# Create object and make payment with stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

So I am trying to create a job object in jobs_controller and I have managed to get the checkout stripe gem to work as described [here](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/rails). So I can make a payment in mywebsite/charges/new , so the api keys are
correct and working as I can see my test payments in the stripe dashboard.

But I now want to create a payment as the user is trying to create a job object, as you can see in the create action inside my jobs_controller.

```
def create
    puts "HELLLOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO"
    @job = Job.new(job_params)
    @job.highlight = true

    raise "Please, check job errors" unless @job.valid?
    @amount = 200 *100

    
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
        :email => params[:stripeEmail],
        :source  => params[:stripeToken]
    )

    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        :customer    => customer.id,
        :amount      => @amount,
        :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
        :currency    => 'usd'
    )

    @job.save
    redirect_to @job, notice: 'Job was successfully created.'

  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    logger.debug e.message
    flash[:error] = e.message
    render :new
end
```

And my _form.html.erb in /jobs

```
<form>
  <%= form_for(job) do |f| %>
      <% if job.errors.any? %>
          <div id="error_explanation">
            <h2><%= pluralize(job.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this job from being saved:</h2>

            <ul>
              <% job.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                  <li><%= message %></li>
              <% end %>
            </ul>
          </div>
      <% end %>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :title %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :title, :class => "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :description %><br>
        <%= f.bootsy_area :description, size: "100x30", :class => "form-control", editor_options: { font_styles: false, image: false, color: false } %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :url %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :url, :class => "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :company %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :company, :class => "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>By posting a job, you agree to our <%= link_to "terms of service policy.", terms_path %></label>
      </div>

      <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
              data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
              data-description="A job posting"
              data-amount="20000"
              data-locale="auto">

      </script>
  <% end %>
</form>
```

But when I try to create a job the payment wont go trough and no object is created and I cant see any errors coming out, I dont see any thing in the heroku logs either so I am lost. Any ideas of where my problem is?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the response code ? What is happening ?

Comment: @TerryRaimondo I have tried to use puts in create action, but nothing comes up in my heroku logs regarding the jobscontroller#create action, its seems like it never enters the create action :/. I used heroku logs --tail and only logs from the jobscontroller#new action comes up, any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you could try to see if you have JS errors ? I think checkout.js should submit the form with token and email params, that's it ?